# Nondimensionalization of PDE with non constants coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to try to solve, by some numerical method, a variant of the Navier-Cauchy equation of motion for an elastic, linear, isotrophic, **not** homogeneus body:

$$ \rho_0 (\ddot{\textbf{u}} - \textbf{g}_0) = \nabla ( \lambda \nabla \cdot \textbf{u}) + \nabla \cdot ( \mu ( \nabla \textbf{u} + \nabla \textbf{u}^{\textsf{T}} ) ) $$

where $\textbf u(x,y,z,t)$ is the unknown displacement vector (Meters), $\textbf g_0(x,y,z,t)$ is a the force field (Newtons/Kilograms), $\rho_0 = \rho_0(x,y,z)$ is the density (Kilograms/Meters^3), $\lambda(x,y,z)$ and $\mu(x,y,z)$ are the Lamé coefficients (Pascals).

I'm not sure if, in this casem where the coefficients $\rho_0$, $\lambda$, $\mu$ are non constants, the nondimensionalization is useful.

If for example I transform the independent variables $(x,y,z) = l_c (\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ and $t = t_c \tau$, the unknow $\textbf{u} = l_c \tilde{\textbf{u}}$, the data $\textbf{g}_0 = g_c \tilde{\textbf{g}}$, and the coefficients 
$\rho = \rho_c \tilde\rho$, $\lambda = G_c \tilde\lambda$, $\mu = G_c \tilde\mu$, where the tilde denotes a nondimensional function, and I do all calculations, I get:

$$ \rho_c \tilde{\rho} \left( \frac{l_c}{t_c^2} \tilde{\textbf{u}}_{\tau\tau} - g_c \tilde{\textbf{g}} \right) = \frac{G_c}{l_c} \nabla \left( \tilde{\lambda} \nabla \cdot \tilde{\textbf{u}} \right) + \frac{G_c}{l_c} \nabla \cdot \left( \tilde{\mu} \left( \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}} + \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}}^{\textsf{T}} \right) \right) $$

or also

$$ \frac{\rho_c l_c}{G_c} \tilde{\rho} \left( \frac{l_c}{t_c^2} \tilde{\textbf{u}}_{\tau\tau} - g_c \tilde{\textbf{g}} \right) = \nabla \left( \tilde{\lambda} \nabla \cdot \tilde{\textbf{u}} \right) + \nabla \cdot \left( \tilde{\mu} \left( \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}} + \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}}^{\textsf{T}} \right) \right) $$

$$ \frac{\rho_c l_c^2}{G_c t_c^2} \tilde{\rho} \left( \tilde{\textbf{u}}_{\tau\tau} - \frac{g_c t_c^2}{l_c} \tilde{\textbf{g}} \right) = \nabla \left( \tilde{\lambda} \nabla \cdot \tilde{\textbf{u}} \right) + \nabla \cdot \left( \tilde{\mu} \left( \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}} + \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}}^{\textsf{T}} \right) \right) \text{.} $$

My idea is to restore the form of the original equation so I can choose for example:

$$t_c = l_c \sqrt{\frac{\rho_c}{G_c}}   \qquad\text{and}\qquad g_c = \frac{G_c}{\rho_c l_c}$$

so that the equation become:

$$ \tilde{\rho} \left( \tilde{\textbf{u}}_{\tau\tau} - \tilde{\textbf{g}} \right) = \nabla \left( \tilde{\lambda} \nabla \cdot \tilde{\textbf{u}} \right) + \nabla \cdot \left( \tilde{\mu} \left( \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}} + \nabla \tilde{\textbf{u}}^{\textsf{T}} \right) \right) \text{.} $$

Now I'm still free to choose a suitable value for $l_c$, $\rho_c$ and $G_c$. If my domain is a shpere of radius $R$, I think a natural choice is $l_c = R$. But for $\rho_c$ and $G_c$? The minimum value of $\rho$ and $\lambda$ and $\mu$? The maximum? A suitable mean?

In this case, are nondimensionalization useful to:

- make numerical methods converges faster/better?
- get some physical insight?

Comment: You choose them to make some of the dimensionless parameters in the nondimensional equation be $1$. Usually, it is preferred to have the remaining dimensionless parameters be either small (preferred if possible) or on the order of $1$.

Comment: @Ian In the way I added?